# Symfony - Set Data with Form Even Listener

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a register form.

When the form is submitted and valid there is a bunch of validation happening like checking if the password  and password_confirm match. 
If not I redirect to the same page with the error message.

But I don't want my user to loose all the data he already filled. 
How can I fill the form with those data. Should I use a FormEventListener?

```
public function register(Request $request, RegisterHandler $registerHandler, Register $register)
{
    if($this->getUser()){
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, $register);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        try{
            $registerHandler->handle($form->getData());
        }catch (UserAlreadyExistException $e){
            $this->addFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
            return $this->redirectToRoute('register');
        }catch (PasswordMatchingException $e){
            $this->addFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
            return $this->redirectToRoute('register');
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    return $this->render('app/pages/login/register.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

My Form Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Your Name',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Your Last Name',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Your Email',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Your password',
            'attr' => [
                'id' => 'password1',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('passwordConfirm', PasswordType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Confirm password',
            'attr' => [
                'id' => 'password2',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ]
        ])
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        //@TODO
    });
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Register::class,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Since you are already in the /register there is no need to redirect. Just remove the redirects to 'register' route and it should work. You cannot redirect and keep post data at same time. 

Form events are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do PasswordMatchingException and UserAlreadyExistException come from?

Usually you would use a [constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraint-configuration) or write your own [validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html), then $form->isValid() would be false and the form would be rendered again with the same data and display the errors. For UserAlreadyExistException you would use [@UniqueEntity("email")](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#basic-usage) and for passwords you should use [RepeatedType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#example-usage).